# How to show button after typing text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

i want to show button on the form after typing something inside input element in **Jsp**.

```
<input type="text" id="phoneNumber" name="Number" maxlength="10" size="15" onfocus="this.value=''" value="Enter your number" autocomplete="off">
<br/><br/>
<span style="color:red" class="title1" id="checkPhone"></span><br/>
<input type="submit" class="sendBtn" id="btSend"  name="btSend" value="NextStep" style="display: none">
```

can you help me?

Comment: Yes we can, but what have you tried sofar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `keyup` event of textbox to detect if something is typed in, also check if the textbox has some text to hide button if it is empty

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eAt6Q/1/)**

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
   if($.trim(this.value).length > 0)
       $('#btSend').show()
    else
       $('#btSend').hide()
});
```

You might need to be specific about the inputs instead of doing it with all input elements e.g you can do it with inputs have some class

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you need?

```
$('#phoneNumber').change(function() {
    $('#btSend').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var inp = $("#txt").val();
if(jQuery.trim(inp).length > 0)
 {
   $("#button").show();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works for you

```
$('#phoneNumber').focusout(function () {
    if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
        $('#btSend').show();
    } else {
        $('#btSend').hide();
    }
});
```